# How do I eliminate a codeblocks on Windows compile error with multiple "first defined here" messages for a single function?

Tags: c

The compile error I get is:

```
obj\Debug\Caruso\Collectiv.o:C:\Users\phil\Simulator2\Caruso\Collectiv.c|27|first defined here|
obj\Debug\Caruso\Collectiv.o:C:\Users\phil\Simulator2\Caruso\Collectiv.c|27|first defined here|
obj\Debug\Caruso\Collectiv.o:C:\Users\phil\Simulator2\Caruso\Collectiv.c|27|first defined here|
obj\Debug\Caruso\Collectiv.o:C:\Users\phil\Simulator2\Caruso\Collectiv.c|27|first defined here|
obj\Debug\Caruso\Collectiv.o:C:\Users\phil\Simulator2\Caruso\Collectiv.c|27|first defined here|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
```

I have tried renaming the function and rebuilding the project with no effect. Deleting the function just moves the notification to another function in another .c file in the project.

```c
int MakPkt( Pnum,  TimW,  DestN){     //make packet
            // TimW=110;
    
            Pcount=Pcount+1;                   //using existing packet array
            Pkts[Pcount][HOPS]=100;              //ensures highest priority
            Pkts[Pcount][PREVIOUS]=NodeNr;
            Pkts[Pcount][LHOP]=100;
            Pkts[Pcount][GROUP]=5;                 //group number of collective
            Pkts[Pcount][TNEXTMOV]=MasterCk+TimW;
            Pkts[Pcount][DESTINATION]=DestN;
            Pkts[Pcount][TSTART]=MasterCk;
            Pkts[Pcount][CPHASE]=Pnum;
        }
```

I have also had a similar error appearing with a couple or array definitions in a header file:

```c
int Incl[3] = {077,07700,0770000}; 
int Excl[3] = {0777700,0770077,07777};
```

I worked around that by removing the definition from the .h file and adding them where necessary with different names in the affected modules

I'm relatively new to c and Linux but have extensive background in large assembly language based projects as well as Fortran. Would I be better off with a different IDE or compiler?

Comment: The function definition belongs in exactly one single `.c` file. In the `.h` file there should only be a declaration for the function.

Comment: Please show the commands and the [mre] that led to this error.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an `#include "Collectiv.c"` (instead of `#include "Collectiv.h"`) somewhere in your code?

Comment: Collective.c is a program module, thanks anyway

Comment: I am beginning to suspect that I have been hacked. I stripped everything out of the offending page and replaced it with a siiingle line:

Comment: I fixed the problem initially by completely removing CB (both windows & Ubuntu) and reloading them. On further investigation I found that debug "remembers" past duplicate declarations and keeps on flagging them even after removal. Renaming the project was a cure. Is there a simpler one?